# How do you use AJAX AlwaysVisibleExtender to Keep the Original size of a control on a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am currently making a asp.net form that will have a Copyright bar at the bottom of the page. I have a panel, which has a width of 100%, at the bottom of the page. I want that to be always visible while people are scroll through the website, but as soon as I add the AJAX ALwaysVisibleExtender control to the panel, it resizes the panel to a small box.

How can I modify the AJAX AlwaysVisibleExtender to keep the original format and at the same time stay on top of my content. I tried adding stuff like style="width:100%" and all sorts of HTML coding, but it doesn't seem to help. It errors out all the time.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show you're current markup (that is not working)?  Also, is the problem the same in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest possibly using some javascript to keep the box the full width of the page (ideally using something like jQuery)

Without seeing what your code looks like, it's hard to know completely, but perhaps add something like this as a script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#<%= pnlCopyrightBar.ClientID %>').width($(document).width()));
    });

    $('#<%= pnlCopyrightBar.ClientID %>').width($(document).width());
});
```